# How to Verify Password Hashes

Tags: php

I am using this to hash passwords: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

```
$hash = password_hash($pass1, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 16));

 if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
        /* Valid */
    } else {
        /* Invalid */
    }
```

It works. It hashed passwords. But I dont know how to verify the password in the login page. I have tried with seesions but it doesnt work with sessions too.

Comment: What is `$password` and `$pass1`?

Comment: Pull the hashed password from the database, use `password_verify($submittedForm, $fromDatabase)` to verify.It's either `true` or `false`.

Comment: encrypt the input password and compare it with db.

Comment: @RoginThomas That won't work with `password_hash()`.. It would work for sha1/md5 hashes, but those you really should avoid.

Comment: Use `password_hash()` in the registration form, and store the result in the database. In the login form you fetch the stored hash from the database and check the user entered password with `password_verify()`.

Answer (score 2):

you have to put the Hash in Database

Step one : create and store the hash in database

```
$hash = password_hash($pass1, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 16));
```

Step two : login

```
$hash = // hash of user from database by unique id 
$password = // string submit by user from login form

if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    if (password_needs_rehash($hash, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 16))) {
        $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 16));
        /* Store new hash in db */
    }
} else {
    /* Invalid */
}
```

Hope it will be help you

Comment: I have created and stored the hash of the password when the user registered.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have done it in the past is in the following steps:

1) User submits their Username/password combination.

2) I see if the Username exists in the database, if it does I pull out that user record from the database, if it doesn't I present a generic error to the user (i.e. wrong username/password combination)

3) I then use the `password_verify` function with the submitted password against the hashed password connected to the user they are trying to log in as.

4) If its true, they're logged in otherwise I present the same generic error to the user (wrong username/password combination)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to hash the password user puts in login page and check if the saved hash in database is equal to hashed password that user sends on login.